# SubSonic 3 and WPF ItemsSource (ComboBox, DataGrid) - selected item not updating more than once

Tags: wpf, combobox, subsonic, selecteditem

When I bind a SubSonic 3 produced IQueryable result to the ItemsSource of a WPF ComboBox or DataGrid, I'm unable to change the selected item in the ComboBox or the DataGrid more than once.  I'm using SubSonic 3.0.0.3 and ActiveRecord.

Here's an example:

In my code:

```
var foo = FooDB.Customer.All();
FooComboBox.ItemsSource = foo;
```

In my xaml:

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="CustomerName" Name="FooComboBox" />
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run application.  Note that there is (initially) no items selected in my ComboBox.
2. Click on the ComboBox. The drop down appears with several customer names.
3. Choose customer name X in the drop down.  The drop down disappears and X is now selected.
4. Click on the ComboBox again.  The drop down appears.
5. Choose customer name Y in the drop down.  The drop down disappears, but X is still selected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A little more info:

I wrote a simple class to wrap the SubSonic generated Customer class (it contains one property, which gets/sets a Customer instance), put that in a collection, and assigned the collection to the ItemsSource of the ComboBox.  With this hack, the ComboBox is working as expected.  But why?  Are one of the Customer class' properties/methods causing problems with the ItemsSource?  (is that possible?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the SubSonic generated class with your own class (which contains one property, which gets/sets the generated class instance) and using that in a collection, works.